# PHP Amazon SES Email Verification

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to verify email domain or send verification through API? I would like my client to confirm their email domain when they create an email campaign in my website.

I am using PHP AWS SDK v2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-ses.html

```
$mailbox_email = 'email@yourdomain.com';

$aws_client = \Aws\Common\Aws::factory(array(
  'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
  'credentials' => array(
  'key'         => AWS_ACCESS,
  'secret'  => AWS_SECRET
  )
));

$ses_client = $aws_client->get('Ses');

$ses_result = $ses_client->verifyEmailIdentity(['EmailAddress' => $mailbox_email]);

// Set bounces, complaint, deliveries notification
$ses_client->setIdentityNotificationTopic(array(
 'Identity' => $mailbox_email,
 'NotificationType' => 'Bounce',
 'SnsTopic' => 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:9:ses_bounces'
));

$ses_client->setIdentityNotificationTopic(array(
 'Identity' => $mailbox_email,
 'NotificationType' => 'Complaint',
 'SnsTopic' => 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:9:ses_complaints'
));

$ses_client->setIdentityNotificationTopic(array(
 'Identity' => $mailbox_email,
 'NotificationType' => 'Delivery',
 'SnsTopic' => 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:9:ses_deliveries'
));

$ses_client->SetIdentityFeedbackForwardingEnabled(array(
 'Identity' => $mailbox_email,
 'ForwardingEnabled' => false
));
```

Answer (score 0):

In AWS SES for Email Domain Verification you need to do a DNS settings either add a DKIM or TXT record which cannot be done using a API except the domain is in Route 53 and you have access to the account. This are the ways to verify email domain. So email domain verification will have to be done manually.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

You can only verify the Email Address using AWS SES API.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html

Comment: hi, i read the doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html but couldnt find anything on how to resend the email verification again if they dont receive the email

Comment: You want to resend from console or from API?

Comment: i want to resend the email verification through API

Comment: Just Rerun the API for  Email verification again for the same email.

Comment: i see. just for clarification. Can i just verify the email address without domain verification?

Comment: Yes you can do that when you send email verification to the email address the receiver will receive email verification link which the recipient has to click on to verify the email address.

Answer (score 0):

> Verify email

```
        //connect Amazon SES
    $ses = new SimpleEmailService($this->AccessKey, $this->SecretKey,'email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com');

    //Get verified mail list
    $list = $ses->listVerifiedEmailAddresses();
    //verify email
    $confirm = $ses->verifyEmailAddress('mail@example.com');
```

> Set topic after verify email

```
$ses = Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory([
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => $this->AccessKey,
                'secret' => $this->SecretKey,
            ],
            'version' => 'latest', 
            'region' => 'eu-west-1'
        ]);


        $ses_client = $ses->setIdentityNotificationTopic(array(
            'Identity' => $email,
            'NotificationType' => 'Bounce',
            'SnsTopic' => 'arn:aws:sns'
        ));

        $ses_client = $ses->setIdentityNotificationTopic(array(
            'Identity' => $email,
            'NotificationType' => 'Complaint',
            'SnsTopic' => 'arn:aws:sns'
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now (Oct 17, 19), you can generate the txt record for verifying domain through the API.

```
$result = $client->verifyDomainIdentity([
'Domain' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
]);
```

[AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-email-2010-12-01.html#verifydomainidentity)